# How to schedule message for Microsoft Teams bot according to timezone?

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I want to send a message to the user from my bot on a specific time interval. Till now I am using agenda for scheduling messages. But the timezone of agenda is 5:30 hours behind my timezone. So it is not sending messages to the user on right time. Is there a way to schedule messages in Microsoft teams?

Let suppose the scenario of birthday wish. Suppose, I want to send birthday wishes from bot to all the users on their birthdays at 9 in the morning every year. And birth dates are stored in database. How can I do that?

Comment: scheduled bot message is part of what they call "proactive" message. See the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet ;

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you'd need to know the time zone of the user. Unfortunately, you don't get this with, for instance, a conversationUpdate event, but there are two other alternatives:

1. You could simply *ask* the user, via the bot, like letting them select a time zone in an adaptive card, or entering their closest city
2. Although conversationUpdate doesn't pass anything useful, a *regular* user message to the bot has both a "timestamp" as well as a "localTimestamp" field. I'm not sure if it's -always populated (it's marked "nullable" in C# on IActivity), but it will contain the local time of the user. You can store that for later reference, to know when to message them.

In terms of actually *sending* the messages via your bot, you'd want to use something called "proactive messaging". You can find more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) to get started.

Comment: How can I schedule a message? Is there any other possible way without knowing the timezone?

Comment: Could you please suggest me a possible way to solve the above scenario?

Comment: oh, I see, you want more guidance on the sending itself. I've updated the answer above, hope that helps